# Evaluation (short-circut) of &= operator

Tags: c++

is `a &= foo();` simply replaced by `a = a && foo();` in C++ or is there more to it?

My concern is the evaluation of `foo()`. Will it be called if `a` is false?

Comment: Yes, it will be called. And no, there's no `&&=` operator :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&&` **does** have embedded short circutting: you're aware of that.

`&` **does not** have any notion of short circutting: it is an operator requiring evaluation of both arguments.

Informally speaking `a &= foo()` is short-hand for `a = a & foo()`. (Actually it's a little deeper than that: `&=` can operate atomically whereas the long-hand version will not since assignment is not atomic. Therefore you can't really think in terms of a compiler making a simple replacement. Not strictly relevant here but worth pointing out.).

Note the single `&` in the unabbreviated form: the cause of the confusion. Therefore there will be no shortcutting.

Comment: Formally (as per the definition in the standard), `a @= b` is identical to `a = a @ b`, except that `a` is only evaluated once.

Comment: @JamesKanze: that's interesting: I've asked as a separate question as I don't know for sure. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288587/equivalence-of-a-b-and-a-a-b. Obviously I'll upvote and even accept an answer from you.

Answer (score 2):

They're not the same, `a &= foo()` would be equivalent to `a = a & foo()`, so bitwise and. There's no short-circuit involved.

Answer (score 0):

That is a [bitwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) `&`, not a logical `&&`.

Because it is a bitwise `&`, the function will be called, since both operands are needed to perform the bitwise `&`.

If you meant a logical `&&`, you need to spell it out explicitly, as you have written:

```
a = a && foo();
```

In the case above, if `a` is `false`, then it should short-circuit and `foo()` will not be called.