# Equivalence of "a @= b" and "a = a @ b"

Tags: c++

It's often mooted (indeed I think even the standard alludes to it), that `a @= b` and `a = a @ b` are equivalent. Here I'm using `@` to stand in for a range of symbols such as `&` and `^`.

However I doubt that they are equivalent at *run-time* especally if `a` is an *atomic type*. For example:

```
std::atomic_int a;
a ^= 1;
```

(which is an atomic way of toggling `a`) is mooted as being equivalent to

```
a = a ^ 1;
```

But, this second way is **not** atomic due to the assignment.

Therefore I doubt their literal equivalence and a compiler (irrespective of what the standard says) is **not** able to change the shorter form to the longer one.

Am I correct?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the C++ standard says exactly what `a @= b` stands for, rather than allude to it.

Comment: User-defined types are one case where these two are different. Another one is `sideEffects() @= b`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The language standard only defines the behavior of the built-in
operators, not the "user defined" overloads.  And from
a language point of view, there is no built-in operator for
`std::atomic_int` (which is formally a "user defined type");
`std::atomic_int` is a typedef for `std::atomic<int>`, which
defines a number of `operator@=` overloads, but no simple `@`.
So for

```
std::atomic_int i;
i ^= 1;
```

the second line becomes:

```
i.operator^=( 1 );
```

but for:

```
std::atomic_int i;
i = i ^ 1;
```

the second line becomes:

```
i.operator=( i.operator int() ^ 1 );
```

One could argue that this is part of what is implied by "the
left hand argument being evaluated twice, instead of once".
More generally, however, the definitions for overloaded
operators are whatever the author of the operator wanted:
`operator+=` could (as far as the language is concerned)
actually subtract, even when `operator+` added.  (I've a couple
of cases where `operator+` actually does `operator+=`.  This is
*not* usually a good idea, and in my case, it only happens with
classes specially designed for use with `std::accumulate`, and
documented to only be used in that case.) The standard simply
doesn't restrict user defined operators

Answer (score 10):

You are correct. Actually, they are not even guaranteed to be equivalent in the general non-atomic case, as a class could provided different overloads for `+=` and `+` which are completely independent.

Comment: It's a pity then that I tagged this as purely C++. In C - where you can't overload the operators - the equivalence would always hold. I won't retag since it would compromise this excellent answer.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in operators have that equivalence, except that `a @= b` only evaluates `a` once, while `a = a @ b` evaluates it twice.

However, these are not the built-in operators, but overloads provided by the standard library. They are treated as separate, unrelated functions, so the compiler cannot change one into the other. (In fact, as noted in the comments, only the assignment operators are overloaded for atomic types - you would have to explicitly load and store the value to use the non-atomic form).

Comment: Actually, it's an interesting case, because there are "user defined" `operator@=`, but no user defined `operator@`.  Normally, this would be signaled as poor design, but `std::atomic` is a special case, where it is (IMHO, at least) justified.  (The alternative would be to not provide the `@=` operators at all.  And one could argue that this would be a better solution.  I prefer the standard solution, but there are valid arguments both ways.)

Answer (score 2):

You can define `^=` and `^` to do completely different things. So, no compiler can't change one to the another just if it wants

Comment: But then you are misusing operator overloading w.r.t. best practices and do code obfuscation instead. But generally, you are not wrong.

Comment: @phresnel: it is *normal* for them to do different things as far as the compiler can tell. In any type where constructing an object has or may have side-effects, they'll have different behaviour. That the programmer can consider it "the same" is a higher-level concern than the compiler knows about. For an example of potential side-effects: calls to code not visible to the compiler. For an example of code (typically) not visible to the compiler: memory allocation.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Of course my comment was with regards to the programmer's view. That they do different things under the hood is something I know very well :)

Comment: @phresnel In the general case, I'd agree, but `std::atomic` is somewhat special.  (Of course, `operator^` could be overloaded to return a proxy, and the `operator=` overloaded on this proxy.  But this leads to a number of other problems.)

Comment: And by the way: am I the only person who is bothered by the fact that `std::atomic` (or `std::string`, or whatever) is consistently called a "user defined type", even though it is in fact defined by the standard, and a "user" doesn't have the right to define it?

Comment: @JamesKanze: about as bothered as I am by the fact that C defines "object" as any region of storage, in defiance of other CS or English-language meanings of the word. I treat it as a jargon meaning of "user" to include "standard library implementer", despite that some standard library types clearly cannot be implemented without compiler support.